# Duplicate disagreement - give me code for range regex q

Tags: discussion, specific-question, dupehammer

There is [Regular Expression for a range values between 0.00 and 15.00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810539/regular-expression-for-a-range-values-between-0-00-and-15-00?noredirect=1#comment76608907_44810539) question that I read as "give me C# regex for 0.00-15.00 range detection".

Instead of downvoting for no research I closed it as duplicate of some other questions asking about similar range checking. Some even had regexes as answers.

Another user suggested that it is not duplicate "Neither of those linked-to duplicates is an answer to the OP's question." and "Maybe they guy has a valid form in mind, maybe he want's to extract from other text".

I don't see why we need more range checking questions, so I don't feel need to re-open question.

Should I have instead:

- downvote and move on
- edit question with links to what I found to be duplicates to demonstrate research and upvote
- find better duplicate
- provide answer
- ignore

Comment: The duplicates are fine.

Comment: Only one of the duplicates has the condition of specifying a numer of allowed decimal places in addition to the number range check (which is what OP needs), so I would say that of the linked duplicates only https://stackoverflow.com/q/4806138/1288408 is a "real" duplicate.